# How to increase the number of steps when moving back the cursor position in office word with SHIFT+F5

Tags: microsoft-word

word by default allows to go back 3 positions. But this is extremelly low, and makes this function almost useless. Even 5 steps would be much better. Is there some way to increase it? I take even regedit solutions.
Thank you

Comment: There is no process in Wo rd to increase this number. I suggest leaving feedback. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-do-i-give-feedback-on-microsoft-office-2b102d44-b43f-4dd2-9ff4-23cf144cfb11 Take a look also at using the Navigation Pane.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/47375-how-increase-number-steps-when-moving-back.html. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: A Message to Forum Cross-Posters https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 0):

Per my research, I found [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/keyboard-shortcuts-in-word-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2), which states that pressing shift+F5 will "move the cursor to the location of the previous revision or last change".
I suggest you go to *File>Feedback* in Word to post your suggestion to Microsoft directly.